# Running Bash Scripts with arguments through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, child-process

Im trying to run a bash script through node.js with `child_process`

the part that is not working in my bash script when I am running the line

```
(echo "PASSWORD"; echo "PASSWORD"; echo "NAME"; echo "ORGANIZATION"; echo "ORGANIZATION"; echo "CIUDAD"; echo "REGION"; echo "PAIS"; echo "yes";echo) |keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Basically, I'm trying to answer different options when I'm running the keytool but its not working (the process is stuck waiting for an option)

In node I am running

```
 exec('./script.sh', {
  cwd: '/Users/MY/Directory'
}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
          console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
          return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }).stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This wont work as each echo happens and only the last echo is even piped to your program.

The way I would handle this is probably with `expect`.

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Also you can use the `-dname` flag to set these fields. Which is way cleaner than dealing with the interactive prompts.

"cn=Mark Jones, ou=Java, o=Oracle, c=US"

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit more on how to use the -dname flag?